# How could I improve my question?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

I just asked a question, [Zombie process (How to exit game properly with JFrame?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24597973/zombie-process-how-to-exit-game-properly-with-jframe), and it has got downvoted.

I am just wondering, what can I do to improve the question? What more information could I provide? How can I make the question more clear?

I do not want to be one of those people with a "shady past", and so would prefer to make my questions as high quality as possible which is why I am asking here.

Comment: You posted a fairly large amount of code in that question. I think you would get a more positive response if you could shorten the code to the minimum that reproduces the problem. Also, you probably tried a number of things to solve the problem before you posted. If you can explain what you already tried, it gives people more information, and shows that you put effort into solving the problem yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Quoted text is a copy-paste from https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234172 by Gilles</sub>

> The first posts queue is a very helpful tool to guide new users. It
>   should be expanded, not removed.
>
> First posts (or early posts, not necessarily just the very first post)
>   warrant more attention for:
>
> guidance in comments, regarding how to improve a question which isn't
>   suitable as posted, what extra information should be provided, what
>   could improve the quality of an answer, etc. spam triage edits, as the
>   user probably often hasn't mastered formatting — this is especially
>   important on sites with MathJax making extra sure that helpful first
>   posts are rewarded by an upvote (as rofl notes, it's especially
>   important to get new contributors to the stage where they can upvote)
>   The first posts queue is all about guiding new users. If it's misused
>   50% of the time, this means that 50% of users are getting this extra
>   chance of guidance. Removing the queue just because it isn't as
>   effective as it should be would be silly.
>
> So yeah, this review queue is terrible and useless Wrong. Dead wrong.
>
> I'm thinking we could probably make this work if we narrowed the focus
>   considerably; less "help new users in some mostly-unspecified way"
>   more "help filter the wheat from the chaff" This seems completely
>   backwards. Helping new users in some mostly-unspecified way is very
>   much what the first posts queue is about! Yes, triage is also involved
>   — there are users (especially spammers) that we don't want to help.
>   But primarily this is about guidance, about helping.
>
> Before the first posts queue in its present form, I used to pay
>   special attention to posts on the front page marked “modified X time
>   ago username 1”. I deliberately went to these posts to provide triage
>   and guidance. This is obviously very approximate: it doesn't catch
>   cases when someone else modifed another post on that page afterwards,
>   sometimes brings me to already-deleted posts, etc. Essentially, what I
>   wanted a list of first (or early) posts requiring special attention,
>   preferably with some system so as to distribute said attention evenly.
>   Which is the exactly what the first posts queue does.
>
> Ideally, a new user's posts should go into the first posts queue as
>   long as the user hasn't been determined to be good or bad. I'd like to
>   see something like this (I haven't thought about the numbers much):
>
> A new account with 1 rep is considered new until further notice. All
>   posts by a new account go through the first posts queue. When a new
>   account reaches 2 posts with a positive score, it is presumed good;
>   posts no longer enter a queue based on the poster. When a new account
>   reaches 2 posts with a negative score, it is presumed bad; posts enter
>   the low quality queue instead of the first posts queue. Posts from new
>   users should enter the first posts queue as soon as technically
>   possible. We want to do triage and guidance as early as possible,
>   ideally while the user hasn't closed their browser yet.
>
> Each post should be seen by multiple pairs of eyes. I agree with the
>   general idea that posts should exit the queue based on actions taken,
>   though it's not as simple as having had a vote up or down. Some posts
>   are just middling. I think the rules for number of reviews should be
>   relatively complex, perhaps a sort of point system (actions grant
>   points whether taken from the review queue or not):
>
> the first upvote or downvote gives 3 points subsequent votes give 1
>   point, but the second vote gives 0 point if it contradicts the first
>   one a close vote or any flag gives 1 point an edit gives 2 points a
>   comment gives 2 points a “no action needed” review gives 1 point a
>   post stays in review until it's acquired at least 4 points, with
>   always 1 mandatory review I haven't thought much about all possible
>   combinations of actions, this is just an idea of what I think the
>   system should be. The idea is to ensure that feedback is provided to
>   the user.

Your post is too long and contains lots of irrelevant information. Nobody wants to read all of it to debug your code for you. You need to pare down the code to [a minimal example that reproduces the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

> I don't see the point in separating questions and answers. This queue
>   is about providing tailored guidance: you never know whether the next
>   post will be good or bad, so why would it matter whether it's a
>   question or an answer?
>
> To combat the serial reviewer problem, we need to combat serial
>   reviewing in itself. This isn't a problem of the first posts queue
>   specifically. Making “no action needed” not count towards badges and
>   rankings might help, though I don't like it much — it penalizes
>   conscientious reviewers because of some bad apples. I had proposed
>   minimum quotas of each action to get badges. The objection was that
>   serial reviewers would turn to acting randomly and undoing their
>   damage would become harder — but I'm not convinced: are we really
>   undoing the damage of serial reviewers now? Alternatively, we can
>   punish serial reviewers: there are now tools to suspend users from
>   reviewing, and we should reset offenders' progress towards badges.
>
> Audits aren't doing a good job of revealing serial reviewers because
>   too many of them are litigious and the ones that aren't are trivial to
>   avoid without really engaging one's brain. However, patterns of
>   behavior can be used to good effect — a user who spends 5s on average
>   and always selects the same action clearly isn't doing a good job. A
>   minimum time per review (with some averaging going on because there is
>   the occasional short review) could be enforced or verified (“you
>   cannot submit more than 10 reviews in 5 minutes, come back in 1
>   hour”); there are ways to make reviewing more annoying for serial
>   reviewers while not impacting conscientious reviewers, and we aren't
>   doing that at all at the moment.

Comment: Ah. So make it easier for people to help me. Thank you.

Comment: You got it in one!

Comment: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  +1 self-demonstrating.  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.